# Replacing non English links with English ones

Tags: discussion, edits, hyperlinks

I found a [couple of postings](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fintl%2F) which contains e.g. [Chinese links](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fintl%2Fzh-CN%2F) to the Android documentation. I think those should been replaced with their English counterparts. In detail just `/intl/zh-CN` needs to been removed. Same for `/intl/zh-TW` and `/intl/ru`.

Should this been cleaned up? I guess this will cause many edits and I'm not sure if this is a good thing.

However when you click such a link, you will been locked for this language by cookie. I just can revert it by deleting the domain cookies to get the English documentation back. So this is also something about usability.

Comment: This is probably something that should be cleaned up with a script. However, some of the answers are literally only that link, and I've seen one where the link was dead.

Comment: Assuming that all has been forgiven... I have seen an post where a foreign person had asked a question (not a bad one) and got an answer (a good one). It just so happened that the person who answered spoke the same language, and helpfully provided a link to some documentation in their native tongue. In that case, I would just include the English link, leaving the foreign one as well.

Comment: I think Stack Exchange can/should do this.

Comment: @Braiam Are you talking about an automated script that queries all SO posts for `/intl/zh-TW`, `intl/ru`, and every other `/intl/XXXX` language code? Because that would simply not work.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice no, something like this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237146/213575

Comment: And another joke dies a harsh death on the Internet, to make room for more cats.  Ironically, Jeff Atwood had the same problem: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-hugging-will-continue-until-morale-improves/  "OK, maybe sometimes my Twitter jokes aren't very good. Well, you know, that's just, like … your opinion, man. I should probably switch from Twitter to Myspace or Ello or Google Plus or Snapchat or something."

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If non English links are part of good answers then they should be edited and corrected.

However, if they are part of low quality, link only answers that do not contribute to the site, then don't bother with editing and instead flag them.

Comment: Keep the original though, so maybe add ` ([English](english link))` to the text.

Comment: @mirabilos Sorry, I don't quite understand what are you saying.

Comment: I was saying: do not _replace_ the nōn-English link, but _add_ an English link to it instead. (As for the low-quality thing, I agree, of course.)

Comment: @mirabilos I see. Well, since Stack Overflow is in English I am not sure how much value would be there in keeping original link. Especially the way you propose. If I would keep original link I would do that the other way around. Replace original link with English and add [Original link](original link)

Comment: Keeping the original link would preserve the original poster's intent more, plus translations can differ, plus while it's in english not everyone's first language is english so it can help, as long as the english version is given too for the "majority" of the visitors.

Comment: @mirabilos I was on a verge of adding your suggestion to the answer, but then it hit me it would be opening Pandora's box. What if original link is for Chinese, and someone drops by and adds additional link for German, soon enough there would be flood of non-English links and all can be justified by what you just said. No. I think we should stick to English.

Comment: nah just what the poster said and English. No reason to add additional non-languages (nor approve edits that do), but also no reason to remove what's there in the first place.